# SNMP - Disk Free - Incorrect Values

Tags: disk-usage, network-monitoring, snmp

just updated Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS and now SNMP Disk Free values are coming back incorrect.

Server still responds to SNMP requests, but the values are all 0.

Is this a bug in an update?